# Dialogflow - handling inputs with multiple intents

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm designing a helpdesk chatbot in dialogflow and currently training it with existing data from my ticketing system. What is the best practice for handling inputs that contain multiple intents? Here is an example with the intents in bold:

"Hi, my name is John Doe and I'm a first year student. I want to know where to **register for classes** and also **reset my enterprise password**. Please help."

So is the solution to ask people to keep things simple up front? I think currently dialogflow will point the user to one of the intents above, but i'm not sure how it decides which intent to match with.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have one intent for each feature that your bot offers, i.e. `RegisterClass`, `ResetPassword` etc. In that case there is no good* way to handle the case where someone asks for two things at once, your users will have to limit themselves to one request at a time. You can however use a [fallback intent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/default-intents#default_fallback_intent) to explain this at runtime. This intent would be triggered if a users utterances matches none of the other intents and could give the user a quick explanation like

> "Sorry, I didn't get that. Please tell me what you would like to do,
>   e.g. 'register a class' or 'change my password'"

This would keep a natural conversation going and alleviate the need to "train" users specifically for your agent.

*You could of course add combined intents like `RegisterClassAndChangePassword`, but that would become very clumsy and most likely not work reliably. You could also try to parse the request in your backend, but then you would essentially circumvent Dialogflow's core feature.